# Accelerate an SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Is it possible to accelerate an SKSpriteNode?

I know the velocity can be set easily with `node.physicsBody.velocity` but how hard would it be to set it's acceleration?

Comment: Did you try `applyImpulse`?

Comment: That wouldn't work but 'applyForce' would.

Comment: Well, `applyImpulse` will accelerate the physics body without much control over it.

Answer (score 6):

Working backwards from newtons second law a motion : F = m.a
You can achieve a desired acceleration by using `applyForce` where the force is the acceleration multiplied by the mass.

```
[node.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(node.mass*acceleration.dx,
                                          node.mass*acceleration.dy)];
```

Answer (score 1):

**applyImpulse** instantly imparts a quantity of energy (in Newton.seconds). Your object doesn't accelerate so much as instantly reach the desired speed. This is unlikely to look very natural as it implies near-infinite power (energy divided by time) therefore is only really suitable for explosions (shooting bullets for example).

**applyForce** applies a force (in Newtons) for the time-interval the simulation runs in (i.e.: 1/60th of a second). This allows you to correctly accelerate an object and simulate many different forces being applied simultaneously (gravity, wind, rocket boost etc.) in different directions.

Also worthy of note is **applyForce:atPoint:** this allows you to specify at which point of the object the force is applied. For example if you were simulating a balloon with a string, the string would apply its weight to the bottom of the balloon, whereas the lift of the base in balloon would be applied to the centre of the ballon. Applying a force elsewhere than at the centre of gravity will cause the object to rotate.

Lastly, you have the corresponding **applyAngularImpulse:** and **applyTorque:** which allow you to influence an object's rotation speed. This is useful for example if you want to keep an object upright despite various bounces: you could apply a torque proportional to the angle (or square it if you want to avoid oscillations).

All this is very well documented here: [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

But if you need more information about the physics themselves then have a look at Wikipedia:
[Newtonian Physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) and associated pages (angular momentum for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to accelerate, then you should change the direction of gravity for the object

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(dx,dy)
```

but this would make everything accelerate, if that is okay

Comment: No, I'm looking to accelerate an individual node without affecting the others.